# How to Read SSE event stream at server side instead of browser

Tags: server-sent-events, event-stream

I am creating an application to read Event Stream and keeps the information on my database.

I have an URL: `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/restconf/streams/mno-vnf-event/json`
headers required: `Accept:text/event-stream`, `Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46o99RtaW4-`, `Content-Type:application/yang-data+json`

Now I want to fetch stream from above API using java (not javascript code), anyone has the idea to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some Java libraries that supports SSE:

- Jersey:  https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/sse.html#sse-client-jaxrs
- Micronaut: https://dzone.com/articles/micronaut-mastery-consuming-server-sent-events-sse
- Spring WebClient: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events (Consuming the Server-Sent Events with a WebClient)

These are the first that come to my mind, but there are undoubtedly more.

Comment: Didn't find any option to add custom headers to make SSE request from Jersey or Spring WebClient.

Want to add the following headers in the request:

`Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46o99RtaW4-`
`Accept:text/event-stream`
`Content-Type:application/yang-data+json`

Answer (score 1):

If the SSE server follows strictly the SSE spec, you can't add any custom headers.

Nonetheless, if it does, have you tried something like that with Spring WebFlux Client:

```java
ResolvableType type = forClassWithGenerics(ServerSentEvent.class, String.class);

WebClient client = WebClient.create();
client.get()
      .uri("http://localhost:8080/sse")
      .accept(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
      .header("MyHeader", "Foo") // Add your headers here.
      .exchange()
      .flatMapMany(response -> response.body(toFlux(type)))
      .subscribe(System.out::println,
                 Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

I have tested this piece of code against a SSE Undertow server. It seems to work: Undertow is able to get the custom header that has been sent.